# CSS not being applied to inserted table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I have a basic task list with due dates. The CSS script for showing overdue dates works. If I add new entries via the from input the css is not applied to overdue items. I have researched event delegation on here and adjusted code to include .on for delegation. Spent a long while trying to solve this but any help would be appreciated.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".add-row").on('click', function() {
            var task = $("#task").val();
            var date = $("#date").val();
            var markup = "<tr><td>" + task + "</td><td>" + date + "</td></tr>";
            $('table tbody').append(markup);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('table td').each(function() {
            var row_date =
                Date.parse($(this).text().replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/,
                    '$2/$1/$3'));
            var now_date = new Date().getTime();
            if (row_date < now_date) {
                $(this).parent('tr').addClass('past');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="task" />
        <input type="text" id="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" />
        <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row" />
    </form>
    <table id="task_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Task</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Mow lawn</td>
                <td>01/02/2017</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Clean car</td>
                <td>01/02/2017</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Empty bins</td>
                <td>01/02/2018</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <style>
    #task_table tr.past {
        background: #ff8a33;
    }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're going to have to show us the CSS if you want help

Comment: Simply move the date compare logic where you are adding dates to table on user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a jsfiddle that gets you partially there. There's still an issue when you load, but that should get you going:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add-row").on('click',function(){
        var task = $("#task").val();
        var date = $("#date").val();
        var markup = "<tr><td>" + task + "</td><td>" + date + "</td></tr>";
        $('table tbody').append(markup);
                checkDate();
    });

        function checkDate() {
            $('table td').each(function() {
                var row_date = Date.parse($(this).text().replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, '$2/$1/$3'));
                var now_date = new Date().getTime();

                if(row_date < now_date) {
                        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('past');
                }
         });
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5bsrt3pv/)

Comment: Very good, I can see the changes of naming the function checkDate, and also using .closest instead of .parent. This has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the CSS to the cells in that row, not to the row itself:

```css
#task_table tr.past td {
  background: #FF8A33;
}
```